# ld cannot find OCCI libraries even if they exist in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: environment-variables, ld, occi

I am just doing some simple OCCI thing, however it compiles a bit strangely

Environment:

- Oracle VM: Centos7 64bit on Windows 8 64bit
- gcc-c++.x86_64
- Simply installed Oracle XE by double clicking the rpm (download pages says
  linux 64bit)

echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH yields: 
`/usr/local/lib64/:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/`

I also tried `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/`
so that it yields
`/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/`

some listing command:
`find /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/ -name lib*`

yields the following:

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/libagtsh.so.1.0
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/libcell11.so
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/libnnz11.so
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/libocci.so.11.1
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/libclntsh.so
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/libocci.so
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/libagtsh.so
and some others....
```

however the compile command says ld cannot find some libraries:
`g++ -o ab -I/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/rdbms/public/ -lnnz11 -lclntsh -locci a.cpp`

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnnz11
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -locci
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried adding `-L/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/`, it successfully compiles however running the program will cause it silently crashes / blocks at the simple line

`Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment();`

no exceptions caught.

Does anyone know some part I did wrong? or are the two issues related?

And by the way, it USED to work like 5 hours ago, when it suddenly stopped working I reinstalled the whole VM and now it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> however the compile command says ld cannot find some libraries: `g++ -o ab -I/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/rdbms/public/ -lnnz11 -lclntsh -locci a.cpp`

Your command is incorrect (and the linker is right to complain). You need to tell the linker where to find the library, and you do that with `-L` flag:

```
ORACLE=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
g++ -I ${ORACLE}/rdbms/public -L ${ORACLE}/lib a.cpp -lnnz11 -lclntsh -locci
```

(Note that your placement of source after library is also incorrect, and I fixed it above. Placement of libraries and sources on link command line [matters](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).)